# Display element as other arbitrary element using css

Tags: css

I know you can use the display: property to display an inline-element as a block-element, and also other like table-cell etc. However, is there a way to make an element display like any other element? Something like

```
div.header{ display: h2; }
```

would be useful. Any way to accomplish this in css, except for overriding all the h2 properties?

Comment: This is possible using CSS Preprocessors like LESS and SASS. See `@include`.

Comment: or add (and style) another common class both for div.header and h2

Comment: Hmm, when using @extend h2; Sass does not include default styles as far as I can see. Only styles that are including h2, like h2.someclass...

Comment: *"Would be useful"*...I doubt it...and what would be the point? Use the elements as they are supposed to be used *semantically* and then style them as required. Regardless, the answer is NO.

Answer (score 0):

If `h2` has the following styles:

```
h2 {
line-height: 24px;
color: rgb(255,0,0);
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

and you want `div.header` to look the same...

You can state this in your css:

```
h2, div.header {
line-height: 24px;
color: rgb(255,0,0);
font-size: 16px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: OK, but I specified in the that I did not want to override the css properties. And your elements would not look the same, as the H2-element also has default styles you need to handle.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but the point of my question was to find out if there was a way to simply have an element inherit all styles from another element, including the default styles.  In your example the elements will not look the same simply because browsers set a margin on header elements, which you don't override.

Comment: Ah, I see!! Your question is about style inheritance. I get where you're coming from now. I'm fairly certain you can do this with javascript. If you're interested in a javascript-based solution, I will edit the post above to demonstrate.